# Is this correct syntax for ES2015 tagged template?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, template-strings, tagged-templates

On [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/) page there is the following code snippet (which can also be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)), demonstrating some use of a template string.  The only explanation or context is the comment at the start, which makes sense to me on its own. However the snippet itself is a mystery to me still.

```
    // Construct an HTTP request prefix used to interpret the replacements and construction
    GET`http://example.com/bar?a=${a}&b=${b}
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Credentials: ${credentials}
    { "foo": ${foo},
      "bar": ${bar}}`(myOnReadyStateChangeHandler);
```

I'm really fine with the string literal itself, it is the context that is confusing me.

Is GET a custom function, possibly loading up some fetch()? If so, is there some naming convention somewhere that is ok with full caps on a method name for GETs and POSTs?
Where would you use a snippet like this? If it is to be inserted into some function called GET, why would
you put it all together like this here, when the function is just going to break it into so many pieces
anyway?

And finally - what's up with the parentheses at the end? This is really the bit that has me asking the question. I can't find any example elsewhere of a string literal followed by a parenthesis. What's going on with this syntax? I've spent so long searching this, that I am tempted to say it is a mistake. If this last bit was missing, the whole thing would make sense as a tag function.

Comment: What you're looking at is a way to construct an HTTP Request that is unique to Javascript, the code in the parenthesis would be the callback function. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I think the example is really inadequate. *Any* function can be called with that syntax. Presumably, the example is meant to imply that somewhere there's a `GET()` function designed as a template "tag" function. Without explaining that, however, it leaves the reader to figure that out and make assumptions about what it does. That makes no sense when the example is designed to help the reader understand what it *can* do.

Comment: The MDN page referenced in the first comment has a much better explanation, with better examples.